# Erroe run synapse Pipline

Tags: azure-synapse

[image]How can i resolve the error bellow ? i don't understant because it's worked before[image]

[image]

Comment: the error is with my question ? no

Comment: it's ok now in the question ?

Comment: In the error it is showing at SinkEmployee. Could you please add the sink configurations?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Synapse Workspace DB connector is currently in public preview.
I also tried to reproduce the same in my environment. I am also getting same error. with the different source types with sink type Workspace DB and getting same error.

[image]

When I tried with other Sink type it worked successfully.

[image]

May be the issue is with the Workspace DB connector sink type
you can use different sink type, or you can [raise](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Support/NewSupportRequestV3Blade/callerWorkflowId/2f36c0f1-dcee-42ae-9d3d-6dbb6275f2d8/callerName/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportOverview.ReactView) Support ticket to Microsoft.